# ASP.NET MVC2 deny access to controller with IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I have a directory that is named admin. 
There is no physical path to this directory, as it is hard-coded as prefix for my administration area.

How can I protect this path with standard-authentification?
I want that only user Admin can login to that area.
But the main page needs to be available for every user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using any of the built in authentication variants:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

**Edit**

To limit to a specific user:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
}
```

**Edit2**

Yes you can, but it's kind of a ***hack***. Create your own class and derive it from `RouteBase`.

```
public class MyRoute : RouteBase
{

     public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase context)
     {
          if (context.Request.Uri == XXX && context.User != YYYY)
              return forbiddenRoute;//redirect to forbidden page.
          else
              return null;
     }
}
```

Then add it in your global.asax.

Comment: is it possible to just say limit to specific user based on routes or based on a specific path?
In don't want to forget one of these flags and being naked.